# 404 Error when creating a helloworld page using django

Tags: python, django

I'm working through the djangobook tutorials and I have reached the point where I create the hello world view and runserver to see the page when I get a page not found (404 Error).

**urls.py code**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^hello/$', hello),
)
```

**views.py code**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

I've copied the code fairly accurately and it should work, if I've missed something please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: `^hello/$` will only match http://localhost:8000/hello/ (ending with a slash), not e.g. http://localhost:8000/hello

Comment: @miku: my browser conveniently displays those identically :)

Answer (score 0):

On trailing slash: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#append-slash is a lifesaver.